# How to get a single element with a model with relations Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models `Driver` `Worker` and `Group`. The models are like this:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    ..... 
    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Driver');
    }
    public function worker()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Worker');
    }

}
```

**Drivers**

```
class Driver extends Model
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
    }
}
```

**Worker**

```
class Workerextends Model
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
    }
}
```

But how can I get a single element with the relationships that I have defined in my models. I have this in my controller but I only get the first element of the table. I need to get the element with the id and also the relations.

```
public function show(Group $group)
    {
        return $group->with(['worker','driver'])->first();
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to get? All workers and drivers of your group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public function show(Group $group,$id){
   $group = $group->where('id',$id)->with(['worker','driver'])->first();  
   return $group
 }
```

in your Route

```
Route::get('/group/show/{id}', 'GroupController@show')->name('group.show');
```